# Xcode & GitHub & SVN

Tags: svn, xcode, github

Wondering if anyone has played around with GitHub's new support for SVN?

Would really like to try this out with Xcode if anyone has could they point me in the right direction on how to setup Xcode SVN etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub's SVN support is [read-only](http://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support). Note the date of the announcement. :-)

Here's an article on [how to use SVN with XCode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html).